# Use bounded integral to find local maximum. If the function $f(x)=\int_0^x-\sin t^2 \ dt$ on $-1\leq x\leq3$, then $f$ has local maximum at which $x?$

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

How do you use a bounded integral to find a local maximum? I didn't know this was even possible.

---

The particular multiple choice problem I'm working with is

> If the function f is defined by $f(x)=\int_0^x -\sin t^2 \ dt$ on the closed interval $ -1 \leq x \leq 3$, then $f$ has a local maximum at $x = ?$
>
> a. $-1.084$
> b. $0$
> c. $1.772$
> d. $2.171$
> e. $2.507$

Comment: This is just *some function* of $x$, and I assume you know how to use the derivative to determine where a function has a maximum.

Comment: Hint: FTC does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question without answering your question directly, you would use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Since $-\sin(x^2)$ is continuous for all values of $x$, then the FTC says that
$$f'(x)=-\sin(x^2)$$ 
Which means that if $f'(c)=0$, then $f$ has an extremum at $c$.
So what values of $c$ in $[-1,3]$ will make this true?